# Query for column value as column alias of a survey result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a problem in building a query of the following scenario. I am listing tables and values for an example:

### Responses Table

```
Q_ID | Response_ID | answer_col_label | answer_value  
10   | 500         | Label_a          | 1  
11   | 501         | Label_b          | 2  
12   | 502         | Label_c          | 3
```

Then in results table, values are as under:

### Results Table

```
Q_ID | Response_ID | answers   
10   | 500         | 502
```

In results table, there is response_id pushed in answers column, which means that user selected this response_id from radio button/checkbox.

Now I want to create a query where I want to show answer_col_label value (Lable_a) in column heading for including all responses of responses table and showing answer_value as selected result under that column heading.

Please help me creating this query in SQL Server. Thank you for time and help.

Comment: This site is about 3D printing. I think you made a mistake, this obviously belongs on a programming/database stackexchange.

Comment: Can you post a sample of how you want the data to be returned by the query? It would be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Use PIVOT

```
SELECT P.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT A.Q_ID, A.Response_ID, A.answer_col_label, B.answers
    FROM @ResponseTable AS A
    INNER JOIN @ResultsTable AS B
        ON A.Q_ID = B.Q_ID 
            AND A.Response_ID = B.Response_ID
) AS S
PIVOT
(
    MAX(answers) FOR answer_col_label IN ([Label_a], [Label_b], <and other labels>)
) AS P
```